# Why wont my ngram field show up when I query it in Solr?

Tags: solr

This is my current code.  The field text is processed as normal text and is working fine.
So my problem is, I am not seeing an optiSearchTXT_ngram upon request.  I see optiSearchTXT just fine, but no optiSearchTXT_ngram field is present.  Is there something wrong with my code or do copied fields/ngram fields not show up?  The field is shown on analysis btw, so it is recognized by Solr, it just does not seem to be copying the information sent to this solr into that field.

```
<field name="optiSearchTXT" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="optiSearchTXT_ngram" type="opti_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" />

<copyField source="optiSearchTXT" dest="optiSearchTXT_ngram" />

<fieldType name="opti_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="25" minGramSize="2" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Any ideas as to why I am not seeing a **optiSearchTXT_ngram** field upon request?

Answer (score 0):

```
<field name="optiSearchTXT_ngram" type="opti_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

This is because `optiSearchTXT_ngram` field is marked as `stored=false`, which means that it won't be returned in response/result.

See [solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) and [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22287584/935083) for more details.

Comment: Oh ok thank you very much!  I thought it would return the index values as well.