# solr difference between qf=text^1 and qf=content^1

Tags: solr

What are the differences between

```
qf=text^1
```

and

```
qf=content^1
```

I've currently got my solr qf setup as:

```xml
<str name="qf">title^15.0 description^9.0 categoryNames^3.0 authorName^1.0 content^1.0</str>
```

Just wanted to know if there's any big differences between text and content.

Schema def:

```xml
<field name="content" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="text" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between these 2 fields is the fact that `content` field is not stored while `text` field is.

To see what it means, you can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287584/solr-index-vs-stored) which explains well what is the difference between `stored` field and `indexed` field.

You can also take a look on [Solr's wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Common_field_options).

Answer (score 0):

text and content are just field names so between those two expressions there is  no difference from a query language perspective (except that you're querying a different field)

As a side note: boosting by 1 makes no sense as 1 (actually 1.0) is the default value