# Solr shows only all result data indexed from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, solr

I am working on the solr-7.2.1 version in which I m importing data from mysql. Everything works great in terms of indexing and importing. My data gets imported from mysql and indexed correctly but when I run a query on admin panel, it doesn't show any results. though, when I type *:* it shows all the indexed documents in the result page. I am new to Solr so cant get what's wrong with this. Please help if you can.

Comment: My intuition says your fields on schema.xml is NOT indexed=true and stored =true, , see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287584/solr-index-vs-stored

Comment: I have double checked and found all are indexed. You know I m getting all documents in results when I type *:*, but no results when typing any search term in the query.

Comment: What does your query look like? What is the content of the field you're searching? What is the type of the field you're searching? What does the analysis page for your collection/core say when you select the field and give the data indexed into the field and your query?