# Solr copy field copied to another field

Tags: java, apache, search, solr, lucene

I have the follows configuration:

```
...

<field name="spellcheck" type="text_spell" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="spellcheck_de" type="text_spell_de" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="spellcheck_en" type="text_spell_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="spellcheck_fr" type="text_spell_fr" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="spellcheck_ja" type="text_spell" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="spellcheck_zh" type="text_spell" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="spellcheck_pt" type="text_spell_pt" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="spellcheck_it" type="text_spell_it" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="spellcheck_low" type="text_spell" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="spellchecksearch" type="text_spell_en" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />

<copyField source="spellcheck_en" dest="spellcheck_low" />
<copyField source="spellcheck_low" dest="spellchecksearch" />
...
```

The **spellcheck_en** field is already populated and it comes correctly copied into **spellcheck_low** field and it is correctly indexing (using luke index viewer I see the index of the field not empty). However, the copy of **spellcheck_low** does not seem to work because **spellchecksearch** is empty. Note: **spellcheck_en** and **spellcheck_low** fields are both indexed and stored, while **spellchecksearch** is not stored but only indexed.
Why is this happening? You could clarify how a field copy works, thanks very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`copyField` instructions aren't evaluated as a graph - the value that was originally submitted for the `source` field, is also used to populate the field given as `dest`.

Since there was no value submitted for the `spellcheck_low` field, the `copyField` instruction ends up copying an empty value (.. or not being executed at all).

In your case, you'll have to have two destinations for the `spellcheck_en` field:

```
<copyField source="spellcheck_en" dest="spellcheck_low" />
<copyField source="spellcheck_en" dest="spellchecksearch" />
```

This will be the same as you tried to implement, since any copy operation will take place before any processing or indexing happens (with the exception of update processors, IIRC).

Comment: So, it happen mainly because copyField use value submitted of source field. It's right?

Comment: Correct. `copyField` is processed first, before the field values are sent further down the chain. And the source is what was originally submitted for the field (otherwise you could end up with looping `copyField` definitions, etc.)

Comment: Now it's clear to me. Thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

spellchecksearch is empty because it's not stored. When a field is indexed but not stored then its only available for searching but it's value remains empty. And it doesn't get returned in the value. 
For details you can read-
[Solr index vs stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287584/solr-index-vs-stored)

I think if you make the field spellchecksearch indexed and stored your problem will be resolved.

Comment: It's right, but if I use this spellchecksearch doesn't empty:

`<copyField source="spellcheck_en" dest="spellchecksearch" />`

with same configuration.

Comment: As MatsLindh suggested you can use-                                              <copyField source="spellcheck_en" dest="spellcheck_low" />
<copyField source="spellcheck_en" dest="spellchecksearch" />