# In SOLR why would a field be non-stored and non-indexed?

Tags: solr, lucene

In Solr's documentation around atomic updates, they mention that a field should be non-indexed and non-stored.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html#in-place-update-example

> An atomic update operation is performed using this approach only when the fields to be updated meet these three conditions:
>
> are non-indexed (indexed="false"), non-stored (stored="false"), single valued (multiValued="false") numeric docValues (docValues="true") fields;

`<field name="price" type="float" indexed="false" stored="false" docValues="true"/>`

What would be an example use-case of doing this?

Wouldn't that mean that it's not queryable and not returned in responses?

Comment: Here is a good example on when this is a good approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287584/solr-index-vs-stored/22298265#22298265

Comment: @HectorCorrea thanks!

Comment: The field can still be used when boosting etc. when you have docValues enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing to understand in this context is that setting `"docValues=true"` is intended as an alternative to `"index=true"`: still making the field "queryable" but in a column oriented (non-inverted) index.

> [...] a way of recording field values internally that is more
>   efficient for some purposes, such as sorting and faceting, than
>   traditional indexing.

Actually being able to make atomic updates in a sort/facet-dedicated-field *is* an example use-case !

Remember that a field with docValues enabled can still be fetched even if set as  `"stored=false"`, allowing for example to retrieve values using the `fl` parameter. That is because docValues are in a way "always" stored, how depends on [`docValuesFormat`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0//core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/DocValuesFormat.html) that defaults to "Memory" (meaning doc values are *stored* in heap).

DocValues fields also relies on `useDocValuesAsStored` that defaults to true, meaning the field behaves as if it were defined as `stored="true"` even if defined as `stored="false"`.