# How to display the individual score for search results in solr?

Tags: solr

I am testing Solr 9.0 with this tutorial:

```
https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/getting-started/tutorial-techproducts.html
```

I used this query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?q=cat:electronics&fl=name
```

In the results displayed, it only gives a masScore. How to display each individual score for each result?

```
"response": {
    "numFound": 12,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 0.5244061,
    "numFoundExact": true,
    "docs": [
      {
        "name": "Samsung SpinPoint P120 SP2514N - hard drive - 250 GB - ATA-133"
      },
      {
        "name": "Maxtor DiamondMax 11 - hard drive - 500 GB - SATA-300"
      },
      {
        "name": "Belkin Mobile Power Cord for iPod w/ Dock"
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read individual document scores as an additional field in the results via the [`fl` (Field List)](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/common-query-parameters.html#fl-field-list-parameter) parameter.

> The `fl` parameter limits the information included in a query response
> to a specified list of fields. The fields must be either `stored="true"`
> or `docValues="true"`.
>
> The field list can be specified as a space-separated or
> comma-separated list of field names. **The string `score` can be used to
> indicate that the score of each document for the particular query
> should be returned as a field.** The wildcard character `*` selects all
> stored fields in the document.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?q=cat:electronics&fl=name,score
```

Comment: Yes, it worked.  What does 'stored=true or docValues=true' mean exactly?

Comment: These are [field properties](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/fields.html#field-properties) defined in the schema. The content of a field has to be _indexed_ to be searchable, and _stored_ to be read. `stored="true"` means the actual content of the field is stored verbatim. `docValues="true"` means the content of the field will be put in a column-oriented structure, and because [docValues are (by default) always stored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56290437/2529954), it also enables a field to be read.